# How can I query the existing records in my imported database in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am now developoing a rails project, but I am using an existing database of MySQL. Well, I have already connected the project with MySQL database, and in former times, I used to created models together with the database migration.

Like, when I create a new Class for the Model part, I used "bundle exec rake db:migration" to create a new database table, and the activerecords are connected.

But now the sequence is a little bit different, I had my database tables first, and then I wanted to query the records using a newly-built class on rails. For example, I had a table of students in MySQL database, and then I wanted to query the records of all the student by creating the new class Student, and create a new search method in the Student Controller.

But now I have not even a clue, because this is new to me, anyone can come for a little help??? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just make the models, Rails is wonderful and that will just work. The gotcha you may run into is if you don't have auto increment primary keys called `id`, but that can be worked around. Try some make models like usual and if you run into a specific issue I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is setting table name.

```
class MyFancyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "myFancy_table_name_1234-5"
end
```